# spring framework mvc localization

Tags: spring, jsp

I am trying to add Internationalization and Localization support to our Spring MVC application. 
I made encoding like this in *-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="messageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
<property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
```

But I found wrong character like below

[image]

I cannot figure out what problem I should fix it. If possible, please let me know.

---

I've already added in jsp page like this:
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Please show your controller.

Answer (score 2):

The `defaultEncoding` property of `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` is used to

> Set the default charset to use for parsing properties files. Used if
>   no file-specific charset is specified for a file.

It has no bearing on how the client is reading the response. If you are generating your response with a `jsp`, you can give it this line at the start

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

so that the client knows that you are providing data encoded with the `UTF-8` charset.

If you are not using a `jsp`, there are other ways to set the `content-type` or `content-encoding`, directly from `HttpServletResponse` or from a returned `ResponseEntity` object.

Comment: beat me for a second. I would like to add, that you should be sure that your properties files are on UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

update your default encoding with:

```
<property name="defaultEncoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
```

and this should work for rendering characters with accents.
At least it works on my spring projects (french and european languages/users)

If this is not an option for you (bigger audience of targetted users) try to add this in your jsp:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    ...
</head>
```